# Groupby puzzle using python

Tags: python, dataframe

I've the following dataframe :

```
import pandas as pd

# Create a list of data
data = [
    ["8582", 1, None],
    ["8586", 2, "8582"],
    ["8585", 2, "8582"],
    ["8593", 2, "8582"],
    ["8584", 2, "8582"],
    ["8590", 3, "8586"],
    ["8583", 3, "8593"],
    ["8597", 3, "8584"],
    ["8587", 3, "8585"],
    ["8674", 3, "8586"],
    ["8589", 3, "8586"],
    ["8588", 3, "8585"],
]

# Create a DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["Nod", "Levels", "Parents"])
```

[image]

I want to achieve the following structure :
[image]

does anyone please know how to achieve this  using python ? thank you

Comment: `to_json(orient='records'))` https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html

Answer (score 1):

you can create what you want using JsonDF library, by making a json/dict from the levels what you want as keys, and then insert to then the values after ordering the list.

the code will be like this :

```py
import pandas as pd
from JsonDF.utils.Json.Json import Json

# Create a list of data
data = [
    ["8582", 1, None],
    ["8586", 2, "8582"],
    ["8585", 2, "8582"],
    ["8593", 2, "8582"],
    ["8584", 2, "8582"],
    ["8590", 3, "8586"],
    ["8583", 3, "8593"],
    ["8597", 3, "8584"],
    ["8587", 3, "8585"],
    ["8674", 3, "8586"],
    ["8589", 3, "8586"],
    ["8588", 3, "8585"],
]

# order data list
for d1 in data:
    parent = d1[2]
    for d2 in data:
        node = d2[0]
        if node == parent:
            data.insert(data.index(d2), data.pop(data.index(d1)))



                
# create Json/Dict
json = Json('data', {}).objectiy()

# adding the keys to json
for d in data:
    level = f"{d[1]}"
    json.insert(level, [])

# adding the values to the keys
for d in data:
    level = f"{d[1]}"
    for key in json.show():
        if key == level:
            json.__getattribute__(key).append(d[0])
        else:
            json.__getattribute__(key).append(None)

# printing the datafrane
print(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(json.show()))
```

the output is :

```
       1     2     3
0   8582  None  None
1   None  8584  None
2   None  None  8597
3   None  8593  None
4   None  None  8583
5   None  8585  None
6   None  None  8588
7   None  None  8587
8   None  8586  None
9   None  None  8589
10  None  None  8674
11  None  None  8590
```

if the dtype ins't important to you can delete the Nones by editing this line `json.__getattribute__(key).append(None)` to be `json.__getattribute__(key).append('')` then the output will be like that

```
       1     2     3
0   8582
1         8584
2               8597
3         8593
4               8583
5         8585
6               8588
7               8587
8         8586
9               8589
10              8674
11              8590
```

you can install JsonDF package with pip `pip install JsonDF`
or using [GitHub](https://github.com/OsamaElsherif/JsonDF.git)

Comment: This is perfect, thank you. is there a way to view this structure in nice way ? like pivot table for example ?

Comment: you can make a pivot table using pandas, `pd.pivot_table(d, index=['1', '2', '3'])` and make the dataframe in a variable like this `d = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(json.show())`

Comment: if this is the answer you want, mark this answer as an answer, to close this question. @hurop